# python unbroundlocalerror local variable 'chances' referenced before assignment

Tags: python

the following code shows error while i execute it, isn't that i have do the assisgnment in the second line before the Looper() executed? However when i add chances = 5 into the first line of Looper(), it works

```
import random

chances = 5
def Looper():
    if chances != 0:
        if real_answer == user_answer:
            print("Gotcha")
            exit()
        elif real_answer < user_answer:
            chances -= 1
            print("Too large")
        else:
            chances -= 1
            print("Too small")
real_answer = random.randint(1, 1000)
user_answer = int(input("This is a guessing game, please guess a         number from 1 to 1000. You have 5 chances"))

Looper()
```

Comment: A variable which is defined inside a function is local to that function. It is accessible from the point at which it is defined until the end of the function..though name of variable inside function and outside are same but they are separate copies with different scope..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides the point that you want `chances` to be a parameter of `Looper` (e.g. `def looper(chances=5):`), you can use `global chances` inside the function to grab a reference to the outside variable.

Better:

```
def looper(chances=5):
    if chances != 0:
        ...
```

Also possible, but global state

```
CHANCES = 5
def looper():
    global CHANCES
    if CHANCES != 0:
        ...
```

Full story:

```
import random

def looper(real_answer, chances=5):
    for _ in range(chances):
        user_answer = int(input("This is a guessing game, please guess a number from 1 to 1000. You have %i chances" % (chances, )))
        if real_answer == user_answer:
            return True
        elif real_answer < user_answer:
            print("Too large")
        else:
            print("Too small")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    real_answer = random.randint(1, 1000)    
    if looper(real_answer):
        print("Gotcha")
```

Comment: any example?I am a newbie:) what is a nonlocal chances?